# Error is ReferenceError: Can't find variable: detail. The - in the object is the culprit

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to fetch details from an api url.
Things worked well without "-" in std-detail but with "-" its showing **Error is ReferenceError: Can't find variable: detail.
std-detail is the object and rest are the attributes

```
var total = document.getElementById("tot");
var nam = document.getElementById("fnane");
var rol = document.getElementById("roll");


var livefeed = {
    "async": true,
    "scroosDomain": true,
    "url": "https://api.xxxx.in/api/v80/simple/details?ids=**std-detail**&vs_class=tenth&include_fname=true&include_lname=true&include_roll=true",

    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {}
    
}

$.ajax(livefeed).done(function (response){
    console.log(response);
   total.innerHTML = response.std-detail.tenth;

  
});
```

Error is ReferenceError: Can't find variable: detail
std-detail is the object and rest are attributes

Comment: Don't mind the "**" in the code as wanted to highlight it as bold but it but it didn't go well
Things are being logged from the url and can be seen in console while inspecting

Comment: Try square brackets: `response['std-detail'].tenth`.